# macbook losing all charge while shut down

Tags: macbook-pro

I bought a MacBook Pro 2017, the version without a touch bar. I charged it to 100% and turned it off to sleep. The next day when I opened it, it didn't start up and didn't respond to the power button. I connected it and it started charging from 1%. It had completely discharged in about 8 hours. Today I charged it to 100%, and within 1 hour, it had dropped to 87% even though it was turned off.

Comment: You likely need a new battery.  It’s at least 6 years old and batteries only have a life expectancy of 3 to 5 years.  even though you aren’t using it, the battery just can’t hold a charge anymore. This is very common.